# How change default parent page for custom template in wordpress?

Tags: wordpress, templates, parent-child, default, parent

**Input data:**
The site contains only pages, no posts.
All pages are created through single templates.
There is only one template that will be used in the future to add new pages.
This template is now written in page.php that would be default template. (This could be redirected without touching page.php,
but this is an extra code for this project)

All these new pages should become children of the page (for example with `id = 77`).
The client could manually select the parent page "name" c `id = 77` each time in the drop-down list.
But this is an unnecessary action and if forget this - there will be problems with the structure in the future.

Automatic selection of the parent page should occur when you click on the "Add New"

**The code probably needs to be added to function.php, it looks probably like this:**

```
 function change_default_parent_page() {
        if(is_page_template('page.php')){
             global $post_parent = '77';
           }
         }
 add_action( 'after_setup_theme', 'change_default_parent_page' );
```

click on the "Add New":
[image: click on the "Add New"]

like now:
[image: like now]

how should it become without using this drop-down menu:
[image: how should it become without using this drop-down menu]

Answer (score 1):

There is a simple code to do it.
Just add this bellow code into your theme's functions.php

```
add_filter( 'wp_insert_post_data', 'set_parnt_page_dynamically' );
function set_parnt_page_dynamically( $data )
{
    if ($data['post_type'] == 'page' )
        $data['post_parent'] = 77;
    return $data;
}
```

77 into my code is the parent page id, you can change it.
Now when user create a new page and hit the publish button, the parent page automatically set.
Try the code then let me know the result, Thanks

Comment: This is it. 
Works perfectly, i can put any parent.
Thanks!

Comment: Hmm...But if i need to change something on other pages with a different template, then all the pages after the update will become the children specified in the filter. 
Need to either turn off the filter each time edit other templates page, or apply filter to the template type, not the post type. 
But I'll try it myself. You so much helped, but I still do not have enough reputation for +.

Answer (score 0):

After a few days of searching, I did not find an solution using templates name
(I think this would be the most correct).

A variant suitable for me-each new page will be the child of the parent I needed, so I used the state of the page when I created it.
So the task is executed and the pages with other templates do not change their parent.

```
add_filter( 'wp_insert_post_data', 'set_parent_page_for_new_posts' );
function set_parent_page_for_new_posts( $data ) 
{
    if ($data['post_status'] == 'auto-draft' )
    $data['post_parent'] = 77;
    return $data;
}
```

Thanks Souvik Sikdar for a hint to attach to wp_insert_post_data and use array `$data`, it's a pity that the developers did not add `$templates_name` to the `$data` array.
But I think someone can give even more elegant solutions.